# How to stop code from executing after error?

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling, ms-access-2010

My form allows users to filter by various controls, including a search box for strings. A separate function, `CalculateSearchString`, processes this search field for filtering (keywords, exact phrases etc); and within this function I use error handling to trap errors caused by incorrect user input (i.e. mucking up the punctuation). The error handling works without a hitch, but I would like the code to **come to a complete stop** if the search input is incorrect.

What I want:

1. user inputs incorrectly formatted search string, clicks on the filter
2. function `CalculateSearchFilter` throws error. Message box: "fix your search terms!"
3. code stops completely, and filter is not applied

What actually happens:

1. user inputs incorrectly formatted search string, clicks on the filter
2. function `CalculateSearchFilter` throws error. Message box: "fix your search terms!" `Exit function`
3. calling procedure `cmdFilterOn` still runs, applying an incomplete filter (as though the search box had been empty)

**Question: How do I halt code execution completely, not just in the function but in its calling procedure(s)?** The function is used in more than one place, so merging it with the calling procedure is not practical.

```
Private Sub cmdFilterOn()
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = CalculateSearchFilter

    'do more stuff
End Sub

Private Function CalculateSearchFilter() As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'do stuff
    If 'user input is wrong, then raise a custom error:
        Err.Raise 50000
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 50000 Then msgbox "Fix your search terms!"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Private Sub cmdYetAnotherButton()
    'which also calls on CalculateSearchFilter
End Sub
```

Moving the input validation to the calling procedure isn't practical either, as it would force me to repeat much of the code in CalculateSearchFilter().

(As I was writing this another solution occurred to me, which is to set `CalculateSearchFilter = "an error occurred"` in the function error handler, and in the calling procedure

`If CalculateSearchFilter = "an error occurred" Then Exit Sub`

...but is there a more "official" answer?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to return a boolean value instead

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdFilterOn()
    Dim strSearch As String
    If CalculateSearchFilter(strSearch) Then

        'do more stuff
    
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CalculateSearchFilter(ByRef strSearch As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'do stuff
    If 'user input is wrong, then raise a custom error:
        Err.Raise 50000
    End If

    CalculateSearchFilter = True
    
ExitHandler:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 50000 Then MsgBox "Fix your search terms!"
    CalculateSearchFilter = False
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function

Private Sub cmdYetAnotherButton()
    'which also calls on CalculateSearchFilter
End Sub
```

**Alternative**:
As mentioned in the comments if you would like to get a string back then I would return an empty string. I would not recommend to return a string like *an error occured* or whatsoever

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdFilterOn()
    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = CalculateSearchFilter
    If Len(strSearch) > 0 Then

        'do more stuff
    
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CalculateSearchFilter() As String
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    'do stuff
    If 'user input is wrong, then raise a custom error:
        Err.Raise 50000
    End If

    
    
ExitHandler:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 50000 Then MsgBox "Fix your search terms!"
    CalculateSearchFilter = vbNullString
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function

Private Sub cmdYetAnotherButton()
    'which also calls on CalculateSearchFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: I think, the function should return a **string**. The one to be used in the next part of the code...

Comment: > I would not recommend to return a string like an error occured or whatsoever
Is there a specific reason for this? Why is using "" better?
I do actually allow strSearch to be empty (no filters = show all records), so this would be a little awkward. Then again, there might be a way around that...

(And yes, as @FaneDuru says, I do need the function to return a string.)

Comment: And how do you know that a string like _an error occured_ is never a filter? And as I passsed in my first version the variable _strSearch_ ByRef you will get back a string.

Comment: @Notiophilus That being the case, then I would use the first approach.

Comment: It looks that `strSearch` should be generated by the function in discussion. At least, this is what I could deduce trying to understand the question meaning. Even if the question is not clear enough, from this point of view... So, I also may be wrong. He did not say anything about my proposed solution, too.

Comment: `strSearch` is filled in my first version.

Comment: I did not refresh the page and I couldn't see a second version...

Comment: @Storax Though I didn't state this in my question, the output of CalculateSearchFilter is an SQL SELECT string, so "an error occurred" would never be an acceptable output. However, I missed your use of ByRef - thanks, I think that does work.